# How to get IP address range of ec2 instances launched by elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My backend is running behind AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I am using a third party API to send SMS.
They are planning to put IP address restriction for their API.

I have to share IP addresses of my server with them.

However, Elastic Beanstalk has scaling configured,
so it launches and terminates the instances dynamically.

Is there a way to know specific range of IP Addresses used by AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the public IP address of your EC2 instance by running this command in the EC2 instance:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

> http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data
>   is a special endpoint.

You can learn more at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

You can add special **User Data** to send this public IP in the first boot to a database or whatever you desire.

Comment: And how would you know which IP area in valid, after scale in? I think better would be to use asg lifecycle hooks to updated your db based on scale in/out.

Comment: You can't get IP range. You can get each IP address by User Data or Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks and save these IP addresses to the database. You can use Elastic IP. But using Elastic IP is a bad practice for a good design.

Answer (score 0):

The full range of AWS pubic addresses is here:

- https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

More info about the addresses is at:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-ip-ranges-json/

This is a large list. For specific addresses of individual instances in your ASG, you would have to query your ASG and its instances for it.